# Laravel 5.7 Email Verification Link Broken

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-mail

At the moment I'm trying to implement the Laravel 5.7 email verification. I have got it so a mail driver will send an email out when registering a user. However, when I click on the email verify button, I get a 404 error.

The URL it sends me is this:

http://localhost/email/verify/16?expires=1543926629&signature=fa3a2a0d90c5752f99b24a7cf7c789edadba5aad2922fff907c289b3364ebceb

However, it is using the wrong URL as the local `APP_URL` in the regular .env is not localhost. Does anyone know how I can tell the email verification to use `APP_URL` instead of localhost? When I rename the URL to the correct URL, I can complete the email verification. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: I just tried it and I'm still getting localhost as the url.

Comment: Not clear from your question - are you using the auth stuff built in to Laravel, or writing your own?  Is the email code (view/controller) your own, or Laravel's? 
 What do you mean by `regular .env` - do you have more than one? What is `url` in `config/app.php` look like?

Comment: I"m using the built in laravel 5.7 email verification code to handle the email verifications. By regular .env I mean my .env file which is set to local environment. The url in app.php is set a https ://core-site.test which is the same url that is in my .env.

Comment: Also yes I have another .env for testing called .env.testing to setup the testing environment

Comment: I've figured out the problem, I was generating the emails incorrect. If anyone else has this issue make sure you read this correctly. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification

Comment: Similar question was asked. Answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61960650/9600517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify in your `Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController.php` if the protected attribute `$redirectTo` value exist in your `routes\web.php` or can be handled.