# URL generator putting "localhost" before domain in Laravel

Tags: laravel, url, environment-variables, laragon

I've been trying to email users a verification link using [signed URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#signed-urls) in Laravel. It seems to work okay, but the link comes out incorrect when it is built using the URL facade.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = URL::signedRoute('confirm', ['user' => $this->user->id]);

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Activate your email address')
                ->line('In order to use the application, please verify your email address.')
                ->action('Activate your account', $url)
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

In the email, the link looks like:

`http://localhost/mydomain.com/confirm/14?signature=3ba4d86827717440f70a3b2f60c913b6e84d550cb9fce8de04a8ba359833ac7c`

The "localhost" part should not be there. However, if I manually delete it in the URL bar, I believe the signed URL things I manipulated the URL and gives me a 401 error. I am running on a localhost environment but I use Laragon's auto virtual host so that I can still run it with a domain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

> APP_URL=example.com

To:

> APP_URL=http://example.com

I guess not specifying "http://" makes it append localhost to the front. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: To be 100% sure, keep env values in double quotes: `APP_URL="http://example.com"`

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes if you are working in virtual environments or docker container, just setting `APP_URL` won't work. Try the following steps.

Step 1: Set your domain in your `.env` file. (Don't forget the double quotes)

```
APP_URL="http://yourdomain.com"
```

Step 2: Add following line before generating your signed route

```
URL::forceRootUrl(\config('app.url'));
```

Step 3: (Optional) Add following line, if you want to force `https` scheme

```
URL::forceScheme('https');
```