# Laravel url() always has "localhost" suffix with APP_URL configured

Tags: laravel, url

I'm currently in a Laravel 7 project. Recently, we need to generate url with url(), everything worked fine in dev environment, however, when we run the code in the production, the url turned to be

> http://localhost/site.url.org/path/to/another/location

,while the url supposed to be

> http://site.url.org/path/to/another/location

We change the APP_URL in .env file or even directly assign site.url.org to the url in config/app.php, neither of them worked, does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Did you try to do `php artisan optimize:clear`?

Comment: @KazikM There is no artisan optimize in 7.x, and we did do cache:clear and config:clear.

Comment: Did you append `http://` or `https://` in the front of domain name in your APP_ENV on production server? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032810/url-generator-putting-localhost-before-domain-in-laravel) question.

Comment: @KazikM Oh yes we didn't make http:// in front of  the url.